# How to extend Qt Widgets that do not have model support by default

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

`CustomMenu` class inherits from `QMenu`. Its custom `setData()` method accepts an argument and sets it to a class variable `model`. I did this because `QToolButton`, `QToolMenu` and `QAction` do not support model/view framework. From what I know aside from all `QList-QTable-QTree Views and Trees` only the `QComboBox` does support `model`.
So the question: would it be possible to extend the functionality of other `non-model widgets` so they could be used as `driven-by-model` widgets too?

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os

class CustomMenu(QMenu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMenu, self).__init__()
        self.model=None

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.model=model
        self.pupulate()
    def pupulate(self):
        for item in self.model.items:
            self.addAction(item)

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Row0_Column0','Row1_Column0','Row2_Column0']

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
    def rowCount(self, QModelIndex):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, QModelIndex):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.items[index.row()])
        return QVariant()
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == Qt.EditRole:                
                self.items[index.row()]=value  
                return True
        return False
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        tablemodel=Model(self)

        tableView=QTableView() 
        tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        tableView.setModel(tablemodel)         
        layout.addWidget(tableView)      

        combo=QComboBox()
        combo.setModel(tablemodel)
        layout.addWidget(combo)

        toolButton=QToolButton(self)
        toolButton.setText('Tool Button')
        toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        toolButton.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Fixed))

        menu=CustomMenu()
        menu.setModel(tablemodel)
        toolButton.setMenu(menu)
        layout.addWidget(toolButton)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDITED LATER: An attempt to implement a QDataWidgetMapper():

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os

class CustomMenuButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CustomMenuButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dataMapper=QDataWidgetMapper()
        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        toolButton=QToolButton(self)
        toolButton.setText('Tool Button')
        toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.menu=QMenu(toolButton)
        toolButton.setMenu(self.menu)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.dataMapper.setModel(model)

        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            action=self.menu.addAction('Item')

            self.dataMapper.addMapping(action, row)

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Row0_Column0','Row1_Column0','Row2_Column0']

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.items[index.row()])
        return QVariant()
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == Qt.EditRole:                
                self.items[index.row()]=value  
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True
        return False

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        tablemodel=Model(self)

        tableView=QTableView() 
        tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        tableView.setModel(tablemodel)         
        layout.addWidget(tableView)      

        combo=QComboBox()
        combo.setModel(tablemodel)
        layout.addWidget(combo)

        menuButton=CustomMenuButton(self)
        layout.addWidget(menuButton)

        menuButton.setModel(tablemodel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDIT 2: Defined a class CustomAction(QAction) with dataChanged = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)...

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os

class CustomAction(QAction):
    dataChanged = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        super(CustomAction, self).__init__(name, parent)

class CustomMenuButton(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CustomMenuButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dataMapper=QDataWidgetMapper()
        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        toolButton=QToolButton(self)
        toolButton.setText('Tool Button')
        toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.menu=QMenu(toolButton)
        toolButton.setMenu(self.menu)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.dataMapper.setModel(model)
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            index=model.index(row,0)
            itemName=model.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject()

            actn=CustomAction(itemName, self.menu)
            self.menu.addAction(actn)

            self.dataMapper.addMapping(actn, row)

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Row0_Column0','Row1_Column0','Row2_Column0']

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.items[index.row()])
        return QVariant()
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == Qt.EditRole:                
                self.items[index.row()]=value  
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True
        return False

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        tablemodel=Model(self)

        tableView=QTableView() 
        tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        tableView.setModel(tablemodel)         
        layout.addWidget(tableView)      

        combo=QComboBox()
        combo.setModel(tablemodel)
        layout.addWidget(combo)

        menuButton=CustomMenuButton(self)
        layout.addWidget(menuButton)

        menuButton.setModel(tablemodel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [QDataWidgetMapper](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdatawidgetmapper.html) class was designed for.  The following blog has a great tutorial covering exactly how to implement it: http://www.yasinuludag.com/blog/?p=98

EDIT: I should add that `QDataWidgetMapper` works with `QWidget` and its subclasses, so `QAction` would not apply. For classes that are not `QWidget` or its subclasses, you might have to implement your own custom model-view binding.

Comment: I just posted an edited version of the same code this time with an attempt to implement `QDataWidgetMapper`. Getting `QDataWidgetMapper.addMapping(QWidget, int, QByteArray): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QAction'
Object::connect: No such signal QObject::dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)`

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit to my post, `QDataWidgetMapper` only works with `QWidget` and with `QWidget` subclasses such as `QLineEdit`, `QComboBox`, etc. If you want to use other classes such as `QAction`, you can't use QDataWidgetMapper; you would need to implement your own custom model-view binding.  I can see that you have added a custom `dataChanged` signal to your `CustomAction` class, but this will never emit because the actions are not part of your table model's dataset (`items`); also, I do not know how data could be changed in the actions since they are non-editable `QAction` objects.